# Python serial read taking longer time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, xbee

I am using Xbee connected to Raspberry pi3, API-mode=2 and sending 29 bytes data from xbee over serial interface and reading (29 bytes) over serial interface, both of which works well as shown in the code below:

```
ser=serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)
while True:
    #SEND DATA
    wrt_time = datetime.now().microsecond
    msg=[0x10,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0xFF,
         0xFF,
         0xFF,
         0xFE,
         0x00,
         0xCC,
         0x66,
         0x00,
         0x00,
         0x01,
         0x00,
         0x03,
         0xFF,
         0x01,
         0x00,
         0x01,
         0x77,
         0x00,
         0x1D]
    ser.write(chr(0x7e)+
              chr(len(msg)//256)+
              chr(len(msg)%256))
    ser.write(''.join(chr(x) for x in msg))
    check=(0xFF - ( sum(msg) & 0xFF ))
    ser.write(chr(check))
    wrt_elapsed_time = datetime.now().microsecond - wrt_time
    print("write time: ", wrt_elapsed_time)

    read_time = datetime.now().microsecond
    data = ser.read(29)
    read_elapsed_time = datetime.now().microsecond - read_time
    print("read time: ", read_elapsed_time)
ser.close()
```

I am also measuring the time taken for data to read and write over serial. The time taken to write is ~700msec and time taken to read is ~140000msec which is quite alot. The problem is `ser.read` is taking quite a lot of time. The same code in C++ is taking 10 times less the time Python is taking so I am sure this is not a hardware issue. I have two questions:
1. What is the reason Python is taking longer? Does Python has the same UART as C/C++ or is there another one implemented at higher level for Python?
2. Is there anyway I can reduce the time taken to perform serial read?

Answer (score 0):

You're saying `msec` (ms) but your code is referencing `microsecond` (µs).  Note that write will be quick since bytes are buffered, and .7ms to write and 140ms to read sound reasonable.  Your read time includes the time for the Pi to actually write the buffered bytes out to the XBee, and then to read the 29-byte response serially.

As always, I recommend 115200bps instead of 9600bps for things like this, so you're reducing the time spend sending bytes over the serial interface.  I also feel that using API mode 2 is more work than using API mode 1, but maybe that's just my personal preference.